# How long do I need my old hosting account after I have moved to another host as well as address?

Tags: web-hosting, google-search-console, htaccess

I had my old website at the********.in and shifted to a .org domain. I also switched the hosting company. Here's what I did -

1. I drove all traffic from old site to the new one with 301 permanent redirects using the htaccess.
2. I confirmed the address change successfully in Google Webmasters tools.
3. The redirection works fine.

So the old htaccess is still at my old host for over a month now.

How long do I need to keep that account for the search results to redirect properly?
I assume the redirection will break if I close my previous account. Is it safe to do so now that sufficient time has passed and I practically don't see any old address in the search results any more?

Answer (score 3):

The goal would be to keep the redirects up as long as possible, ideally forever. Why? Users will have bookmarks with the old URLs and other websites will have links to the old domain. These may never go away and you would like to keep them working if at all possible. That's just good usability (i.e. a good user experience).

You could easily accomplish this by pointing your .in domain to your new website and putting your 301 redirects there as well. That will keep the old URLs alive so anyone who finds and uses one will be able to find the content.

If that is not possible, or your only concern is search engines finding your new content, you can terminate the old hosting and redirects when you're confident the search engines have adequately updated their indexes to reflect your new URLs. You "practically" don't see any old URLs in their index which means you do still see a few. Is is acceptable that those pages may be starting from scratch in the search engines? If so, terminate your old hosting. If not, you need to keep waiting for the search engines to get caught up to your redirects before you pull the plug. You need to decide on how important those pages are to your search engine strategy.

Basically, it's your call.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, by 'practically' I mean there are some leftovers from some static sites I created in the past. Places where I slipped my URI to encourage folks to visit. I have taken care of them now, but I must have missed a few. I don't really care about this minuscule portion. 

Thing is I will hold on to my previous domain name. So here's what I will do. I will transfer the old domain to my hosting company. Does this sound good?